# Docker "invalid reference format"

Tags: linux, image, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm coming back to docker after several months away and am having trouble installing an image on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance.

The error being generated is:

```
invalid reference format
```

And here's the command, which I have from notes taken at the time:

```
docker run -ti --privileged=true -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 8080:8080 -p 2008:2008 -p8084:8084 -p 2021:2021 kanjisoft/centos_pa_one_ system /usr/sbin/init
```

I've tried some solutions I found on SO, but so far no luck.

Comment: There is a space before `system`. Can that cause problems ?

Comment: I think the problem is I wasn't logged in docker, but I'm not sure. Anyway, it seems to be fixed now. Thanks.